# Angular $httpProvider interceptors stopped working for 'ng-include' after adding "UI Grid" to the app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I am trying to add [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) to my application, following introduction tutorial [Tutorial: 101 Intro to UI-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro) and faced following issue.

First, the **grid works**, I can create it in controller and bind to view, but
as soon as I add it to the project (just add as a module, without actually using it anywhere) interceptor that worked previously is not fired anymore, more specifically it is needed for view template loading with **ng-include** (see some code excerpts below).

EDIT : Please note that **ng-include** works, it just does not go through the interceptor, but works as there is none.

- Angular 1.4.8
- UI Grid 3.2.1
- jQuery 2.2.0

What I tried :

1. Using other Angular versions,
2. Tried init interceptor with factory,
3. Changed order of modules in init array,
4. Tried other jQuery version.

Has anyone faced such an issue, perhaps with other modules?

HTML :

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="app.views.layout as vm">
            <div ng-include="'/App/Main/views/layout/header.cshtml'"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="angular-animation-container row">
                    <div ui-view class="shuffle-animation col-xs-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Angular application initialization :

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngSanitize',

    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.jq',

    'ngTouch'
    'ui.grid'

    'abp',

]);
```

Interceptor registration :

```
var abpModule = angular.module('abp', []);

abpModule.config([
    '$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function ($q) {

            return {

                'request': function (config) {
                    if (endsWith(config.url, '.cshtml')) {
                        config.url = abp.appPath + 'AbpAppView/Load?viewUrl=' + config.url + '&_t=' + abp.pageLoadTime.getTime();
                    }

                    return config;
                },

                'response': function (response) {
                    if (!response.config || !response.config.abp || !response.data) {
                        return response;
                    }

                    var defer = $q.defer();

                    abp.ng.http.handleResponse(response, defer);

                    return defer.promise;
                },

                'responseError': function (ngError) {
                    var error = {
                        message: ngError.data || abp.ng.http.defaultError.message,
                        details: ngError.statusText || abp.ng.http.defaultError.details,
                        responseError: true
                    }

                    abp.ng.http.showError(error);

                    abp.ng.http.logError(error);

                    return $q.reject(ngError);
                }

            };
        }]);
    }
]);
```

Comment: In my module initialisation, I have ui.grid not ui-grid... could help?

Comment: It was typo here, updated the Q.

Comment: How do you know your interceptor is not working? Have you tried adding some breakpoints and debugging?

Comment: I tried debugging to some extent, but I am not too strong in JS and angular so I don't know the best place to start. I get that I should start somewhere where those declarative directives are 'parsed' and executed, but did not dig that deep, yet. If you can point me to some more concrete place, that would be great.

Comment: @Phil I had a breakpoint in interceptor which is hit as soon as I remove ui-grid. Also logic that is in interceptor is not executed as I see it from how application behaves. Currently I have no doubt that it's not working.

Comment: That's very odd. I didn't see anything in the ui-grid source code that would interfere with interceptors. Could you try renaming your `abp` module to something more unique, eg `.module('edgars.abp', [])`

Comment: Also, where did you put the breakpoint? I'd go with the first line in your `'request'` handler (`if (endsWith(config.url, '.cshtml')) {`). It's possible something is adding query params on to the request and it no longer ends with ".cshtml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set it up from scratch and it works now. Looks like I missed some minor configuration typo somewhere. Also apparently ui-grid doesn't interfere with angular http interception, so conclusion is that it was false alert.